# GNU Make Single Target Generates Multiple Files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I currently have a tool which generates multiple files given a single input.  So given a file "a.parent", it will generate a bunch of unknown named files such as "b.child", "c.child", "z.child", etc.  This is all dependent on what lives within "a.parent".

My question is, how can I properly construct a makefile target for this such that 1) it won't run the tool more than once since a single run will generate all of them, 2) if any of the generated files are deleted, it will rerun the tool again and re-generate all of them, 3) if "a.parent" is newer than one of its dependents, it will rerun the tool, and 4) I do not have to list each and every child file within the Makefile itself as I really don't care what is generated, only that it is generated.

The problem, at least to me, is that Makefiles are built around knowing exactly what your final state should be.  However, in this case, I want it to only care roughly what it is.

Comment: If there's a way to get the tool to spit out the names of the files it will create you could probably use that the way you can use the gcc `-MD` (and friends) functions to generate `.d` make include files to handle some amount of this for you. The variability of the prereqs is probably going to bite you at some point though even if you do this. Though I suppose the advanced auto-dep stuff from our resident MadScientist might help here too.

Comment: The question seems to imply that it has to be implemented as a single target, but this seems a bit of an artificial limitation.  I should think that it would be easier to utilize a number of targets that server to detect when to run the tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A makefile like the one below may suffice.

This is the idea: As a proxy target for the multiple unspecified `*.child` files
that your tool may generate, use a *manifest* of those files that is created by
the same recipe that creates the files. The recipe deletes the stale `*.child` 
files and manifest, then runs your tool on `a.parent` to make the new `*.child` files,
then makes a new manifest of the new `*.child` files.

The rule for making this recipe is:

- The manifest does not exist, or
- the existing manifest is older than `a.parent`, or
- the existing manifest is older than some `*.child` file, or
- the existing manifest is untrue, i.e. the set of `*.child` files named in
  the manifest differs from the set that exists.

Details are explained in the comments:

```
.PHONY: all clean

# $(manifest) will be the space-punctuated list of files, if any, that are
# listed in 'manifest.txt', if it exists, else the empty string.
manifest = $(shell if [ -f manifest.txt ]; then cat manifest.txt; fi)

# $(outputs) will be the space-punctuated list of '*.child' files, if any, in
# the current directory, else the empty string
outputs = $(shell ls -1 *.child 2>/dev/null)

# Default target:
# If there is any mismatch between $(manifest) and $(outputs)
# then clean and remake. Else just make 'manifest.txt'
ifneq '$(outputs)' '$(manifest)'
all:
    $(MAKE) clean && $(MAKE)
else
all: manifest.txt
endif

manifest.txt : a.parent $(outputs)
    $(MAKE) clean && ./tool.sh a.parent && ls -1 *.child > $@

clean:
    rm -f *.child manifest.txt
```

In the recipe for `manifest.txt`, `tool.sh` stands for whatever tool you
are running on `a.parent`. To test the makefile, I simply used:

```
#!/bin/bash
# tool.sh

while read line
do
    echo "This is file $line" > $line
done < $1
```

together with `a.parent` containing the names of the `*.child` files to be
generated, one per line, e.g.

```
b.child
c.child
d.child
```

(So for my `tool.sh`, `manifest.txt` will just contain the same lines as
`a.parent`.)

This solution isn't bulletproof, of course. For instance if someone deletes
some `*.child` files both from the filesystem *and* from the manifest, the
make will not notice. Also, an explicit `make manifest.txt` will do nothing
even if someone falsifies the manifest. That loophole can be closed with some
complication of the makefile, but precautions against such sabotage-like
eventualities as these are probably not vital.